# TensorFlow Lite Android app crashes on start

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a machine learning based android application that predicts one of the two classes `0` or `1`. I am passing 14 integers in an array for prediction in my model.

```
for i in range(length):
    print(np.argmax(pred[sample[i]]))
```

I have converted my model to tflite using the following

```
#Write out Keras save file
keras_file="linear.h5"
keras.models.save_model(model,keras_file)

#Convert the Keras file to TensorFlow Lite
converter=lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model=converter.convert()
open("linear.tflite","wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I have also added the following in build gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
}
aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
        noCompress "lite"
}
```

I have made 14 `EditText` boxes for the user to input the numbers, a `TextView` to display predicted values and a `Button`. Here is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:context=".Input_Activity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="166dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="RBCC"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText11" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="WBCC"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/outputNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="412dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="PCV"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText9" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hemoglobin"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText14"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText8" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Potassium"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText13"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText7" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Sodium"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="S Ceatinine"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="BGR"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="RBC"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Sugar"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Albumin"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="S Gravity"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Blood Pressure"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Find my organ!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/outputNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/outputNumber"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my java code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.*;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import org.tensorflow.lite.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Input_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputNumber1,inputNumber2,inputNumber3,inputNumber4,inputNumber5,inputNumber6,inputNumber7,inputNumber8;
    EditText inputNumber9,inputNumber10,inputNumber11,inputNumber12,inputNumber13,inputNumber14;
    Button inferButton;
    TextView outputNumber;
    Interpreter tflite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

        inputNumber1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputNumber2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        inputNumber3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        inputNumber4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        inputNumber5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        inputNumber6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        inputNumber7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        inputNumber8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        inputNumber9=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        inputNumber10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        inputNumber11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        inputNumber12=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        inputNumber13=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        inputNumber14=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        outputNumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputNumber);
        inferButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        int getText1=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber1.getText().toString());
        int getText2=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber2.getText().toString());
        int getText3=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber3.getText().toString());
        int getText4=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber4.getText().toString());
        int getText5=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber5.getText().toString());
        int getText6=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber6.getText().toString());
        int getText7=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber7.getText().toString());
        int getText8=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber8.getText().toString());
        int getText9=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber9.getText().toString());
        int getText10=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber10.getText().toString());
        int getText11=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber11.getText().toString());
        int getText12=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber12.getText().toString());
        int getText13=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber13.getText().toString());
        int getText14=Integer.parseInt(inputNumber14.getText().toString());

        final int attributes[]={getText1,getText2,getText3,getText4,getText5,getText5,getText6,getText7,
                getText8,getText9,getText10,getText10,getText11,getText12,getText13,getText14};

        try{
            tflite=new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        inferButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                int prediction=doInference(attributes);
                //float prediction=doInference(inputNumber.getText().toString());
                outputNumber.setText(attributes.toString());
            }
        });
    }
    //public float doInference(String inputString){
    public int doInference(int [] attributeArray){
        int[] inputVal=new int[14];
        for(int i=0;i<14;i++) {
            inputVal[i] = attributeArray[i];
        }
        //Output shape is [1][1]
        int[][] outputval=new int[1][1];

        //Run inference passing the input shape and getting the output shape
        tflite.run(inputVal, outputval);

        //Inferred value is at [0][0]
        int inferredValue=outputval[0][0];

        return inferredValue;
    }
    //Memory-map the model file in Assets
    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor=this.getAssets().openFd("linear.tflite");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
}
```

The app doesn't start at all and crashes without an error. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add some logs to see if `loadModuleFile()` gets called at all, and if it succeeds